# XML STRING to XSLT to C# class object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I don't have much experience in XSLT transformation so thought may be i can get some help here.

I am receiving this big xml string from through MSMQ in my .NET program. Lets says example as below:

```
<ROOT>
<PO>
  <PONUM> A101 </PONUM>
  <DESCRIPTION> THis is sample  PO </DESCRIPTION>
  <ADDRESS> Addresss here </ADDRESS>
  <ExtraInfo1> Any Info </ExtraInfo1>
  <ExtraInfo2> Any Info </ExtraInfo2>

<POLINE> 
  <POLINENUM> Line1 </POLINENUM>
  <NAME> Line 1 </NAME>
  <DATE> 2009-01-01 </DATE>
 <ExtraCol1> Col1 </ExtraCol1>
 <ExtraCol2> Col1 </ExtraCol2>
 <ExtraCol3> Col1 </ExtraCol3>
 <ExtraCol4> Col1 </ExtraCol4>
</POLINE>

<POLINE> 
  <POLINENUM> Line2 </POLINENUM>
  <NAME> Line 2 </NAME>
  <DATE> 2011-11-21 </DATE>
 <ExtraCol1> Col1 </ExtraCol1>
 <ExtraCol2> Col1 </ExtraCol2>
 <ExtraCol3> Col1 </ExtraCol3>
 <ExtraCol4> Col1 </ExtraCol4>
</POLINE>

<POLINE> 
  <POLINENUM> Line3 </POLINENUM>
  <NAME> Line 3 </NAME>
  <DATE> 2012-01-07 </DATE>
 <ExtraCol1> Col1 </ExtraCol1>
 <ExtraCol2> Col1 </ExtraCol2>
 <ExtraCol3> Col1 </ExtraCol3>
 <ExtraCol4> Col1 </ExtraCol4>
</POLINE>


</PO>
</ROOT>
```

Now I need xslt transformation to get some selected fields out of it and the finally get the result in .NET Class object for further processing:

C# Classes as below:

```
public class PO
{
    public string PONUM { get; set; }
    public string PODESCRIPTION { get; set; }

    public List<POLINES> POLines { get; set; }

}

public class POLINES
{

    public string POLINENUM { get; set; }
    public string LINEDESCRIPTION { get; set; }
}
```

So finally in the PO class object I need 
PONUM = "A101" 
PODESCRIPTION= "THis is sample  PO"

And then three POLINES in the 
public List POLines { get; set; }

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need XSLT. Use XmlSerializer. It simple and short.

```
PO po;
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PO));

using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
{
    xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("PO");
    po = (PO)xs.Deserialize(xmlReader);
}
```

Your classes should look like:

```
public class PO
{
    public string PONUM { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("DESCRIPTION")]
    public string PODESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("POLINE")]
    public List<POLINES> POLines { get; set; }
}

public class POLINES
{
    public string POLINENUM { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("NAME")]
    public string LINEDESCRIPTION { get; set; }
}
```

Which xml node must conform to the LINESESCRIPTION property? I have written `NAME` in the attribute. Change it to the right.

Comment: @user2739418 to elaborate slightly, the reason you don't need xslt is because that is a stylesheet template for xml, it is used for displaying xml, not for getting data out.

Comment: @Crowcoder: I got it now. As XML string is very big and I need only part of it so thought might be XSLT will help here. Thanks for suggestions